# Binding in Xamarin.Forms does not work after web API request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make simple app which will provide features to read/write data to database trough an Web API. 
I have view model which is bind to view, but it is not working properly after web api get request, even that call was successfully done. I've tried to check value  with display alert, value is correct, but it is not presented in view part, exactly in one label.  Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SOSEUApp.Pages.NotePage"
         Title="Dnevnik">
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="GET" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"></ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"></ActivityIndicator>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="{Binding Date,StringFormat='Date: {0}'}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class NotePage : ContentPage
{
    NoteViewModel nvm = new NoteViewModel();
    public NotePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = nvm;
    }

    private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nvm.IsBusy = true;
        nvm.Notes = await App.NotesWebApiService.GetAll(nvm.CurrentActiveNote.Route);
        nvm.GetLastNote();
        nvm.IsBusy = false;
        await DisplayAlert("Info", nvm.Date.ToString(), "Close");
    }
}
```

public class NoteViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

```
    IList<Note> notes = new List<Note>();
    public IList<Note> Notes
    {
        get { return notes; }
        set { SetProperty(ref notes, value); }
    }

    private Note currentActiveNote = new Note();
    public Note CurrentActiveNote { get { return currentActiveNote; } }

    public string Date { get { return currentActiveNote.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"); } }
    public string OrderedNumber
    {
        get { return currentActiveNote.OrderNumber.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            string v = currentActiveNote.OrderNumber.ToString();
            SetProperty(ref v, value);
            currentActiveNote.OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt16(v);
        }
    }


    public string Description
    {
        get { return currentActiveNote.Description; }
        set
        {
            string v = currentActiveNote.Description;
            SetProperty(ref v, value);
            currentActiveNote.Description = v;
        }
    }


    public void GetLastNote()
    {

        notes.OrderBy(a => a.Date);
        currentActiveNote = notes.Last();
    }

}
```

public class BaseViewModel : DataModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

```
    bool isBusy = false;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }

    string title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would help to explicitly name the property ;-)

Comment: the only property you are binding is Date, and your VM does not fire any PropertyChanged events for Date when it is updated

Comment: In which way it can be changed?

Comment: you need to fire a PropertyChanged event when Date changes - presumably this will happen when currentactivenote changes, but you need to figure that out

Comment: Do you have a try with `PropertyChanged` to solve this problem?If other problems , you can show.

Comment: I've just called SetProperty method and passed desired values there. It works, but I am not sure how good it is.

Comment: @Dejan Great ! If other problems ,I will update my answer.Thanks  in advance for marking .

Comment: @ Junior Jiang - MSFT Thank you too for answer and sorry for this long time waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just called SetProperty method and passed desired values there. It works

Said as Jason, you need to fire a `PropertyChanged` event when Date changes.Here is [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) for reference.

Generally, usually writed in `Set` methods.As follow:

```
 private string propertyname;

 public string PropertyName
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref propertyname, value); }
        get { return propertyname; }
    }
```

Or write as follow:

```
 public string PropertyName
        {
            set
            {
                if (propertyname!= value)
                {
                    propertyname= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return propertyname;
            }
        }

bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
        return false;

    storage = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

When data of model change , this will be invoked automatically.